# Angular-ui calendar error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I'm trying to configure the angular-ui calendar but I have an error when I run it.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.eventsWatcher.onChanged (http://localhost/fisioGest/js/calendar.js:262:41)
```

I can see the events and everything seems to work right but this error and I can't click on the events.

This the calendar controller of my app.js:

```
app.controller('main-controller',function($scope){
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();
this.tab=1;
this.titulopagina='Escritorio';
this.selectTab=function(setTab) {
    this.tab=setTab;
};
this.isSelected=function(checkTab) {
    return this.tab===checkTab;
};

  $scope.eventSources = [
[
    {
        "title": 'All Day Event',
        "start": new Date(y, m, d)
     },
     {
        "title": 'Long Event',
        "start": new Date(y, m, d - 5),
        "end": new Date(y, m, d - 2)
    }
  ]
];

$scope.calendarOptions = {
   calendar: {
   height: 500,
   editable: true,
   header: {
     left: 'title',
     center: '',
     right: 'prev,next basicWeek month agendaDay'
   },
 }
};


});
```

And this how I define my calendar:

```
<div id="calendar" ui-calendar="calendarOptions.calendar" ng-model="eventSources " class="p-relative p-10 m-b-20"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of [calendar.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/blob/master/src/calendar.js), the line in question appears to be...

```
event._start = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start);
```

It's likely you're missing [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). Take a look at their [demo page](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/blob/master/demo/index.html) and make sure you've included all the dependencies of [fullcalendar.js](http://fullcalendar.io/) (which is the library doing the heavy lifting under the covers) and that they're loaded in the proper order...

```
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>

<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/gcal.js"></script>
<script src="../src/calendar.js"></script>
<script src="calendarDemo.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, the order was one of my mistakes. The other one was the libraries that I was using. I included some libraries from my bootstrap theme that doesn't work right with the fullcalendar.js Thanks!!

Comment: why do you include `jquery-ui`?